# Javascript return reference to jqXHR from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Recently I abstracted a bunch of AJAX calls into a function using the `$.post()` method. My idea was to use the `jqXHR` object returned by `$.post()` to add standard error handlers and such (via `.fail()` `.done()` `.always()`) to remove code duplication. I then thought that I could return the `jqXHR` object from the method to the original calling function so I could add additional handlers to do more context-specific things.

However, the `jqXHR` object returned seems to be a copy of the original object, not the object itself. As such, its state never gets updated by the original call so none of my additional `.done()` functions get executed.

Is it possible to return a reference to an object in JS? I have a C++ background, so is there a way to mimic the "return pointer to object" functionality in JS?

I know there have been discussions on `pass-by-reference/value` on here, but I couldn't find one dealing specifically with `Deferred` objects

EDIT: example code

```
function AJAX(url,data,onSuccess) {
    var jqxhr = $.post({url,data});
    jqxhr.done(onSuccess);
    jqxhr.fail(displayError());
    return jqxhr;
}
...
function example() {
    var dfrd = AJAX("example.php",data,successFunc);
    dfrd.done(alert("Hello, World!"));
}
```

The `.done()` & `.fail()` within the AJAX function get executed normally, but the `.done()` within `example()` never executes because `dfrd.state()` is always `pending`

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your code. What you're attempting to do is certainly possible if the logic is correct.

Comment: Have you verified that at least one of the intended `.done()` calls is is resolving? You will not get a copy just by returning/passing an object in JS as all variables are handled as reference types.

Comment: Added skeleton code to show what I'm trying to do, sorry about not adding that originally

Comment: Apart from not passing the callbacks as *functions*, this code (the `return` parts) should work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pass-by-reference/value, which is about *calling* functions. And no, there is nothing special about deferreds, they're just objects. And those are always reference values, no syntax does copy their contents.

Comment: @BlackBelt2025 Please post complete code that demonstrates the issue, not just a skeleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be a timing issue.

It appears that, with multiple `.done()` functions, there is a slight delay when the function receives a response from the `$.post()` call. So my `onSuccess(resp) {}` that was passed to the `AJAX` function would execute after the `alert()`. The particular `onSuccess` function I was using to test had a page refresh call in it, which would close the alert before I could see it.

I have a C++ background, so I guess I need to upgrade my JS testing procedures.

Thanks to all who commented!